# Can't merge models with two different entities

Tags: core-data

I try to modify my model file, but when I build and run it, the console outputs the error as mentioned in the title, "Can't merge models with two different entities", I try to delete the original model file and create a new one, the error is still there. I have checked [this post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/core-data-migration-problems.html), but the question is I cannot find the .momd directory or previous versions of the model file in the main bundle, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've received the same message after changing an entity. This worked for me:

1. Opened the resources folder in a shell (something like /Users/[name]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[number]/Applications/[alphanumerical]/[appname].app/).
2. Moved all directories with the .momd suffix to another folder outside of the project.
3. Opened the Documents folder and deleted the stored data (I named it "store.data", it is set when you create a persistent store). WARNING: This means you will loose all db entries of course!

Without issue 3 the application may not be able to open the database because something in the db model has changed.